# Spark job stuck at running process

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I use docker-compose to make a cluster of Spark and Kafka. When I tried to consume a topic by submitting it to this cluster, the job was always stuck and not executed.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: spark-cluster:1.0
    container_name: spark-master
    hostname: spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_MASTER_HOSTNAME=spark-master
      - SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
      - "6066:6066"
      - "7077:7077"
      - "8080:8080"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5" # Adjust as needed
          memory: 256M  # Adjust as needed
    # command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    networks:
      - spark-network

  spark-worker-1:
    image: spark-cluster:1.0
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY = 4g
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "4" # Adjust as needed
          memory: 5G  # Adjust as needed
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    # command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker
    networks:
      - spark-network

  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.9
    container_name: zookeeper-server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  kafka1:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.5
    container_name: broker-1
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9093,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper 

  kafka2:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.5
    container_name: broker-2
    ports:
      - "9094:9094"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9094,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9094,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper  

  kafka3:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.5
    container_name: broker-3
    ports:
      - "9095:9095"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=3
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9095,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9095,INTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper  
  
networks:
  spark-network:
    driver: bridge
```

and my consumer.py:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
import os
scala_version = '2.12'
spark_version = '3.5.0'
packages = [
    f'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_{scala_version}:{spark_version}',
    'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.5.0',
    'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:3.0.0',
]

spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .master("spark://172.18.32.1:7077") \
   .appName("kafka-example") \
   .config("spark.jars.packages", ",".join(packages)) \
   .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
# Địa chỉ của Kafka broker
# kafka_brokers = "localhost:9092"
kafka_brokers = "localhost:9095"

# Định nghĩa Kafka topic bạn muốn đọc dữ liệu
kafka_topic = "mytopic1"

# Đọc dữ liệu từ Kafka
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_brokers) \
  .option("subscribe", kafka_topic) \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .load()

# Hiển thị dữ liệu từ Kafka
castDf = df .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
query = castDf.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

The output when I run this code:

```
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/11/28 23:08:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.

[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]
```

And I look at the Job on UI:
[Master UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZBHY.png)
However, when I submitted this code to standalone cluster, it worked fine.

Can sb help me, please? Sorry for my bad English.

I hope for a solution to this problem. By the way, the image "spark-cluster:1.0" I built from "bitnami/spark:3.5"